# Get distinct results using LINQ GroupBy for complex entity relationships?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Here's a quick overview of my relationships:

```
one Account has many AccountRoles
one AccountRole has many UserAccountRoles
many UserAccountRoles can have one User
```

What I need to get is a set of all `User`s for one `Account`.

How can I do this in LINQ?

Edit:

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var dto = _context.Set<Model.Account>()
    .Find(account.Id);

if (dto == null)
    return null;

var userAccountRoleDTOs = dto.AccountRoles
    .Select(ar => ar.UserAccountRoles);

var userDTOs = userAccountRoleDTOs
    .Select(uar => uar.Select(uar2 => uar2.User));

return userDTOs;
```

`userDTOs` is a collection of collections at the `return`. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Ic I've already tried building the expression myself but it hasn't made much sense. Each time I try to either `Select()` or `GroupBy()` certain entities, the method I call exposes more collection extension methods rather than the properties I'm trying to access.

Comment: You should install LinqPad and try the query in there. You get better visualization of your queries and that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ultimately all you want is a flattened collection for the one user, you should be able to use `SelectMany()` to flatten the one-to-many relationship and then call `Distinct()` at the end:

```
var users = dto.AccountRoles
    .SelectMany(ar => ar.UserAccountRoles.Select(uar => uar.User))
    .Distinct();
```

Or, in query form

```
var users = (from ar in dto.AccountRoles
             from uar in ar.UserAccountRoles
             select uar.User)
            .Distinct();
```

Comment: Hmm then maybe I don't understand the relationships correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can go the other way around:

```
from u in context.Users
where u.UserAccountRoles.Any(uar=>uar.AccountRole.Account.Id == someAccountId)
```